# If L is regular, so is L2 (proof using closure properties)

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I've got a question that asks me to explain how if a language L is regular, then so is:

$M=\{s \in \{a, b\}^* |\ \exists\ t \in L\ such\ that\ |s|_a = |t|_a\}$

I believe I would have to get M into the form: $M=\{a^i |\ i\geq0\}$ since we know that any equation of that form is regular, but I'm not quite sure how to go about that using closure properties.

Comment: $M$ is not necessarily equal to $a^*$.

Answer (score 3):

Here are several possible ways of proving that if $L$ is regular then so is $M$.

**Method 1**

Show first that the language
$K = \{ a^r : |s|_a=r \text{ for some } s \in M \}$.
You can obtain $K$ from $L$ by deleting all letters other than $a$. Then show that $M$ is regular by "undeleting" all letters other than $a$.

**Method 2**

Construct an NFA for $M$ directly, given an NFA for $L$. At each step, the new NFA accepts non-$a$ letters gratuitously, both in the input and in its simulation of the NFA for $L$. It also reads $a$, but then must also simulate an $a$ transition on the NFA for $L$. Finally, it accepts whenever it can get the NFA for $L$ to be at an accepting state.

**Method 3**

Parikh's theorem shows that $K$ (defined in Method 1) is eventually periodic. That is, for some integers $m,p$ and sets $A \subseteq \{0,\ldots,m\}$, $B \subseteq \{0,\ldots,r-1\}$ we have
$$
K = \{ a^i : i \in A \} \cup \{ a^{m+rj+i} : j \geq 0, i \in B \}.
$$
Given this, we can construct a DFA for $M$ directly (exercise).